# VB returning a DATE via a search

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have various search boxes in my program (one per form) that is coded to bring results back by various methods and it works beautifully, so long as the returned results are in Integer format. My current problem is I am working a new form and need the List Search Box to show all results found with the searched criteria by the REPAIR_DATE column, which is obviously a DateTime field and not an integer.

My current code as follows:

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
    Dirty()

    If cbColName.Text = "SEARCH BY" Then
        MeMsgBoxSearchCriteria.ShowDialog()
    Else : lbSearchResults.Items.Clear()
        Select Case MaintenanceDataSet.Maintenance_Table.Columns(cbColName.Text).DataType
            Case GetType(Integer)
                DV.RowFilter = cbColName.Text & " = " & tbSearchInput.Text.Trim
            Case GetType(Date)
                DV.RowFilter = cbColName.Text & " = #" & tbSearchInput.Text.Trim & "#"
            Case Else
                DV.RowFilter = cbColName.Text & " Like '*" & tbSearchInput.Text.Trim & "*'"
        End Select

        If DV.Count > 0 Then
            For ix As Integer = 0 To DV.Count - 1
                lbSearchResults.Items.Add(DV.Item(ix)("ID"))
            Next
            If DV.Count = 1 Then
                lbSearchResults.SelectedIndex = 0
                Dim ix As Integer = MaintenanceDataSetBindingSource.Find("ID", CInt(lbSearchResults.SelectedItem))
                MaintenanceDataSetBindingSource.Position = ix
            Else
                lbSearchResults.Visible = True
                lbSearchResults.BringToFront()
            End If
        Else
            ' Display a message box notifying users the search criteria is not found.   
            MeMsgBoxNoSearch.ShowDialog()
        End If
    End If
    Cursor = Cursors.Default
End Sub

Private Sub lbSearchResults_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lbSearchResults.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim ix As Integer = MaintenanceDataSetBindingSource.Find("ID", CInt(lbSearchResults.SelectedItem.ToString))
    MaintenanceDataSetBindingSource.Position = ix
    lbSearchResults.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Currently I am getting only a Record ID or IDs on return and not on the REPAIR_DATE column.

I tried redefining :

```
CInt(lbSearchResults.SelectedItem.ToString)
```

to

```
CDate(lbSearchResults.SelectedItem.ToString)
```

and it ERRORS WITH "value of type 'integer' cannot be converted to 'date'."

I truly am at a loss how to get this REPAIR_Date to come back as a result.

I am still fairly new to VB and not sure how to properly bring the REPAIR_DATE results back as opposed to an integer. I do get results but when clicking on one of the returned results it is supposed to load that record. When choosing a returned value it causes the program to abort with the above listed error mainly because it is looking to return a integer not a date. I truly understand why the error message and why it fails, I just do not know how to resolve it.

Using the same code above in my other forms works flawlessly and brings back my LOAD_NUMBER which is an integer. Obviously minor changes were made to the code to accommodate my need for the current form.

Before someone asks or demands why I have not tried DeBugging... I am not real proficient with understanding the Debug feature yet and though I have attempted numerous times to use Debugging it only shows me it is getting results from the ID field and returning the ID integer. So that is not real helpful since it is bringing back exactly what the code currently is telling it to do.

lbSearchResults.SelectedItem.ToString is a hidden listbox that becomes visible and shows the returned items on search. I then can chose which result I want from that listbox & it loads the relevant record. Probably not the most efficient way to do this but I am still learning and it works on the other pages.

Jaxedin: Your obs is correct... this is where the issue lies.  The code is designed to bring all results to a clickable listbox (in this case by date).

The reference to DV is as follows: `Private DV As DataView` 
I am pretty certain the issue is within the Private Sub lbSearchResults_SelectedIndexChanged sub because if I try to change ix to be a Date it says cannot change date to integer (obviously) and this is where I get lost. I hope this is a bit clearer... ??

---

Answering MIC:

Yes the primary key is the ID field. I am not trying to convert the ID to a date. I am looking to find the search criteria in any record. Once that is found I want it to show the REPAIR_DATE column result in the listbox. When I then click on a date it would load the record... The ID field is set so it knows which record to load.

I have a CB that has a of datacolumns in the DB I want to search through. By choosing a specif data column the search criteria only looks in that column, not the entire record.  I have a TB that the user inputs the search criteria.

As an example, the user would search for "alternator" and choose APU_REPAIR_DESCRIP as the column to search in. Any repair record that has the searched word Alternator would return and this works, only I get the record ID number(s) as opposed to the repair date(s). 
I am using MS SQL 2015 as my DB.

I do not know what else of the code you need to see to further understand my request.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Plutonix, Trust me this is NOT a small program. The page I am requesting assistance on is 479 lines of code alone not including the plus 1200 lines n my "default" form and 6 other forms of near equal length or more. I posted only the relevant code on the form to my issue.

Comment: Are you sure it is not a typo? You are searching for a Date in the "ID" column.

Comment: What's the result of this code lbSearchResults.SelectedItem.ToString ?

Comment: lbSearchResults.SelectedItem.ToString is a listbox that shows all the returned items on the string, I then chose which result I want and it then loads that record.

Answer (score 0):

Why you think you need this line?

```
 CDate(lbSearchResults.SelectedItem.ToString)
```

The code posted doesn't have enough detail or explanation to tell, so we have to guess. Do these tables all have a primary key named "ID", which is an integer?
In that case, all that

```
CInt(lbSearchResults.SelectedItem)
```

is doing is unboxing the integer value which is stored as an object in the listbox items.

So it is not clear why you want to convert that value to a date. If you can explain that there's more chance someone will be able to help you. Or if you can debug your routine to see what it does right and what it does "wrong" and explain that.

e.g. Is your listbox being populated correctly? To filter by the date, you use

```
cbColName.Text & " = #" & tbSearchInput.Text.Trim & "#"
```

This may or may not be doing what you want depending on the database provider.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx

Maybe it would help to take the advice from Eric Lippert posted by plutonix, where it says to explain (to yourself) why each line of your program is obviously correct.